# Django расширенная регистрация

Tags: django

Есть две формы, одна для регистрации пользователя, а вторая - расширенная форма, связанная с моделью User. Как при регистрации подкинуть их двоих? Вот с такой функцией рендерится только одна, вторая форма даже не подхватывается.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegForm(request.POST)
        form_profile=ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form_profile.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()     

            user_profile = form_profile.save(commit=False)
            user_profile.save()

            return render(request, 'registration.html', {
                'form': form,
                'form_profile': form_profile
            })            
    else:
        form = UserRegForm()
        form_profile=ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form, 'form_profile': form_profile})
```

В темплейте 
`<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }}<input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться"></form>`

Answer (score 0):

{% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }} ***{{ form_profile.as_p }}***

Ты забыл вывести вторую форму

Еще тебе придется подсовывать во вторую форму созданного пользователя. То есть сначала проверяешь, что регистрационная валидна, сохраняешь ее. Созданного пользователя отправляешь во вторую форму через initial. Потом проверяешь ее валидность и сохраняешь. Если вторая форма невалидна, выкидываешь свое исключение

Таже нужно будет обернуть в try-except свю эту проверку и работу с формами, и вyenhb try, нужно обернуть в транзакцию

```
...
if 'POST' in request.method:
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            # проверка форм и сохранение
            # если че то не так - исключение
    except <ваше исключение>:
        # скорее всего вам ничего не надо делать тут, ибо ошибки уже будут в формах
...
```

[transaction.atomic дока](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)